# python how to invoke classmethod if I have only it's object

Tags: python, class-method

Assuming I have class

```
class Class(object):
   @register_method_to_later_execution      
   @classmethod
   def my_class_method(cls):
   ...
```

and `@classmethod` object. like this `a = Class.my_class_method` I need to be able to start executing it only if I having an `a` object. Is it possible to do that? and if possible - how It could be done?

---

The problem that I creating reference a at the moment of class creating (in decorator `@register_method_to_later_execution` for my_class_method) during the import

At that moment I just only have an object, and if I later trying to execute it, it throws 
`class method is not callable`

Comment: Possible duplicate of (deleted) [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25364839/python-how-to-invoke-classmethod-object)

Comment: Why didn't you just try it?

Comment: Please show what you mean by "creating reference a at the moment of class creating".

Comment: What does `@register_method_to_later_execution` do?

Comment: Add method to the dictionary, map it with name `method_a` for example, and further based on that mapping I could get object `a` and when I will have object, I should be able to execute it somehow

Answer (score 2):

Kinda trivial to test this  yourself.

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...     @classmethod
...     def my_class_method(cls):
...         print "hello world"
... 
>>> a = MyClass.my_class_method
>>> a
<bound method type.my_class_method of <class '__main__.MyClass'>>
>>> a()
hello world
```

Edit: If I understand you correctly from your edit (and I'm not at all sure that I do), it looks like you're trying to reference a class method before the class has actually been defined? That is not possible.

Use the `@staticmethod` decorator instead as that does not pass in the class variable as an argument.

Edit2: If you need the method to be a class method because you need access to the class variable for some reason, then you're out of luck and I would suggest rethinking your approach, as this one  seems very strange to me and almost certainly isn't a good one :)

Answer (score 0):

Just call it as you normaly would. Example:

```
In [1]: class Foo(object):
   ...:     @classmethod
   ...:     def my_method(cls):
   ...:         print('in my method')
   ...:

In [2]: foo = Foo()

In [3]: foo.my_method()
in my method

In [4]: Foo.my_method()
in my method

In [5]: method_reference = Foo.my_method

In [6]: method_reference()
in my method

In [7]:
```

Comment: This isn't quite the same situation - the OP has a name referencing the class method itself, not an instance of the class

Comment: You are right, I missed that. I have edited example and added example that OP is looking for.