# Defered invocation of a python classmethod obtained in a decorator

Tags: python, python-decorators, python-typing, class-method

I have a decorator meant to wrap a classmethod like this:

```py
class Class(object):
   @register_classmethod      
   @classmethod
   def my_class_method(cls):
       ...
```

My decorator gets a `classmethod` object.  When I attempt to call it, it throws `class method is not callable`.

Here is a sample, with an overly-simplified decorator implementation:

```py
from typing import Callable

all_methods: list[Callable[[type], None]] = []

def register_classmethod(classmeth: Callable[[type], None]) -> Callable[[type], None]:
    all_methods.append(classmeth)
    return classmeth

class Class(object):
    @register_classmethod      
    @classmethod
    def my_class_method(cls) -> None:
        print(f"Hello from {cls}.my_class_method")

    @classmethod
    def run_registered_classmethods(cls) -> None:
        for classmeth in all_methods:
            classmeth(cls)

Class.run_registered_classmethods()
```

While `mypy --strict` is perfectly happy with the typing, at execution I get:

```
$ python3 testscripts/test-classmethod-call.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../test-classmethod-call.py", line 20, in <module>
    Class.run_registered_classmethods()
  File ".../test-classmethod-call.py", line 18, in run_registered_classmethods
    classmeth(cls)
TypeError: 'classmethod' object is not callable
```

Now, I am indeed refactoring code that did not have that explicit `@classmethod` on `my_class_method`, and that code did run fine:

```
$ python3 testscripts/test-classmethod-call.py 
Hello from <class '__main__.Class'>.my_class_method
```

However, with the above type annotations, `mypy` dutifully points out that we're trying to register an *instance method* here:

```
testscripts/test-classmethod-call.py:10: error: Argument 1 to "register_classmethod" has incompatible type "Callable[[Class], None]"; expected "Callable[[type], None]"  [arg-type]
```

Note: I think this is also the problem faced in [python how to invoke classmethod if I have only it's object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25365633), but its initial formulation was likely not enough on-the-point.

## interpretation and start of a solution

It looks like what we get in this context is the descriptor object underlying the class method.  I'd think that we would need to bind it in our wrapper descriptor, eg. using `MethodType` as [shown here as of 3.11](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#class-methods):

```py
class ClassMethod:
    "Emulate PyClassMethod_Type() in Objects/funcobject.c"

    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def __get__(self, obj, cls=None):
        if cls is None:
            cls = type(obj)
        if hasattr(type(self.f), '__get__'):
            # This code path was added in Python 3.9
            # and was deprecated in Python 3.11.
            return self.f.__get__(cls, cls)
        return MethodType(self.f, cls)
```

But we cannot pass the classmethod object to `MethodType`, and have to dig it up in its (undocumented AFAICT) `__func__` member.

Now this does the job:

```py
    @classmethod
    def run_registered_classmethods(cls) -> None:
        for classmeth in all_methods:
            bound_method = types.MethodType(classmeth.__func__, cls)
            bound_method()
```

This however brings us back to a new typing problem: the `classmethod`-decorated method has type `classmethod`, but is annotated as `Callable` for user programs to make sense of it, which causes `mypy` to complain:

```
testscripts/test-classmethod-call.py:19: error: "Callable[[type], None]" has no attribute "__func__"  [attr-defined]
```

We can teach him about the real type by way of `assert(isinstance(...))`, and finally have working and well-typed code with:

```py
    @classmethod
    def run_registered_classmethods(cls) -> None:
        for classmeth in all_methods:
            assert isinstance(classmeth, classmethod)
            bound_method = types.MethodType(classmeth.__func__, cls)
            bound_method()
```

This works but `assert` does have a runtime cost.  So we will want to give a hint in a better way, e.g. using `typing.cast()`:

```py
    @classmethod
    def run_registered_classmethods(cls) -> None:
        for classmeth in all_methods:
            bound_method = types.MethodType(cast(classmethod, classmeth).__func__, cls)
            bound_method()
```

But if `mypy` is happy with this on the surface, using its `--strict` option shows our typing is not as precise as it could be:

```
testscripts/test-classmethod-call.py:20: error: Missing type parameters for generic type "classmethod"  [type-arg]
```

So `classmethod` is a generic type ?  Pretty sure I did not find any hint of this in the doc.  Luckily, `reveal_type()` and a bit of intuition seems to hint that the generic type parameter is the return type of the class method:

```
testscripts/test-classmethod-call.py:21: note: Revealed type is "def [_R_co] (def (*Any, **Any) -> _R_co`1) -> builtins.classmethod[_R_co`1]"
```

(yes, *ouch!*)

But if `cast(classmethod[None], classmeth)` reads OK to `mypy`, `python` itself is less than happy: `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`.

So we also have to have the interpreter and the type-checker to look at different code, using `typing.TYPE_CHECKING`, which brings us to the following:

```py
import types
from typing import Callable, cast, TYPE_CHECKING

all_methods: list[Callable[[type], None]] = []

def register_classmethod(classmeth: Callable[[type], None]) -> Callable[[type], None]:
    all_methods.append(classmeth)
    return classmeth

class Class(object):

    @register_classmethod      
    @classmethod
    def my_class_method(cls) -> None:
        pass

    @classmethod
    def run_registered_classmethods(cls) -> None:
        for classmeth in all_methods:
            if TYPE_CHECKING:
                realclassmethod = cast(classmethod[None], classmeth)
            else:
                realclassmethod = classmeth
            bound_method = types.MethodType(realclassmethod.__func__, cls)
            bound_method()

Class.run_registered_classmethods()
```

... which passes as:

```
$ mypy --strict testscripts/test-classmethod-call.py 
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
$ python3 testscripts/test-classmethod-call.py 
Hello from <class '__main__.Class'>.my_class_method
```

This seems overly complicated for something we'd like to be simple and readable, and possibly a generic helper like the following could be provided to make all of this more usable - I'm not really happy with it, even though it passes all the above tests:

```py
_ClassType = TypeVar("_ClassType")
_RType = TypeVar("_RType")
def bound_class_method(classmeth: Callable[[type[_ClassType]], _RType],
                       cls: type[_ClassType]) -> Callable[[], _RType]:
    if TYPE_CHECKING:
        realclassmethod = cast(classmethod[None], classmeth)
    else:
        realclassmethod = classmeth
    return types.MethodType(realclassmethod.__func__, cls)
```

It does not handle arbitrary arguments to the class method, which we can likely get around to using [ParamSpec](https://peps.python.org/pep-0612/).  But this still makes use of several implementation details of `classmethod` (`__func__` and the generic type parameter): [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) says nothing about them.

- Shouldn't there be a simple way to do that ?
- Is there any better way ?

## Edit: curated summary of answers so far

There are tons of info in those answers, thanks :)

What I find most useful in those:

- we cannot today write an annotation that would cause a method decorated with another decorator than `@classmethod` to get its first parameter `cls` to be of type `type[Class]` instead of `Class` (@droooze)
- as a consequence we have several families of options, none of which are perfect:

  1. live with the fact that the method to be decorated does not have a class method signature; let the decorator register method before wrapping it with `classmethod` to avoid dealing with the latter's internals, and then return the wrapped version (@chepner).

     Note that when we need to use `cls` as a type in our classmethod-that-is-not-one-from-the-inside-for-the-typechecker, we can do something like:

     ```
     @register_classmethod
     def my_class_method(cls) -> None:
         klass = cast(type[Class], cls)
         print(f"Hello from {klass}.my_class_method")
     ```

     It is sad the class name has to be hardcoded, and the type annotation for the argument to `register_classmethod` has to be further massaged if we want to do better than `Callable[[Any], None]`
  2. live with the explicit addition of `@classmethod` and with us making use of its internals, which can also be annoying as forcing ue of that additional decorator causes an API change (@droooze)
  3. tell the type-checker that our decorator is special like `classmethod`, and that its first parameter is a `type[Class]` where it would have been otherwise annotated as `Class`.  Drawback is (aside from the cost of writing and maintaining a plugin), this requires a separate plugin for each static checker.

Answer (score 1):

Class methods *aren't* callable; they define a `__get__` method that returns a callable `method` instance that will pass the class to the underlying function as the first argument.

I might let `register_classmethod` both store the *function* and return a class method:

```
all_methods: list[classmethod] = []

def register_classmethod(classmeth: classmethod) -> classmethod:
    all_methods.append(classmeth)
    return classmethod(classmeth)

class Class(object):
    @register_classmethod      
    def my_class_method(cls) -> None:
        print(f"Hello from {cls}.my_class_method")

    @classmethod
    def run_registered_classmethods(cls) -> None:
        for classmeth in all_methods:
            classmeth(cls)
```

This way, `run_registered_classmethods` doesn't need to worry about the descriptor protocol: it's just running the underlying function directly.

Comment: Interesting idea, but does not pass type-checking: `cls` in `my_class_method` is not annotated as `type[Class]` like with `@classmethod`, and using `def my_class_method(cls: type[Class])` gets rejected by mypy too.

Comment: I fixed the obvious problem (changing the return type of `register_classmethod`); however, that's probably not ideal, as it hides the type of the wrapped function.

Comment: More importantly, mypy still reports `Argument 1 to "register_classmethod" has incompatible type "Callable[[Class], None]"; expected "Callable[[type], None]"`: as @droooze points out without `@classmethod` getting `cls` typed as `type[Class]` and not as `Class` is a bit of a problem.

Comment: Oh, duh, right. Well, it's receiving a `classmethod` object, not a callable. As far as I know, `classmethod` is not generic in the argument or return-value types of the underlying function. `register_classmethod` doesn't *care* about the underlying type, except for the fact that you have typed the `all_methods` list. But that is *also* wrong, as it's a list of class methods, not callable objects. `all_methods: list[classmethod] = []`, then `def register_classmethod(class_meth: classmethod) -> classmethod` is about as accurate as you can get.

Comment: Note `classmethod` still acts as if it was generic in the return type. Maybe we could stick with `Callable` annotations by writing a mypy plugin to teach that the decorator is akin to `@classmethod` would allow to get past that problem.

Comment: `classmethod` is generic in its return type according to the type annotation (you can refer to `typeshed`, see https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/3c24501bb788ca8eb67259b3fb9849f512c5f1f6/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L128-L139). All type checker implementations bundle some state of `typeshed` to perform their built-in type inference, so `typeshed` is the go-to reference. Very unfortunately, the runtime implementation disallows a generic type argument, so e.g. `classmethod[None]` causes a runtime error.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in decorators `@property`, `@classmethod`, and `@staticmethod` are likely to be special-cased by each of the 4 major type-checker implementations, which means that interactions with other decorators may not make any sense, even if you theoretically have the type annotations correct.

For `mypy`, `@classmethod` is special-cased such that

1. it is transformed into a `collections.abc.Callable` even though `classmethod` doesn't even have a `__call__` method;
2. the callable it decorates has its first parameter transformed into `type[<owning class>]`.  In fact, the only way you can even get a `type[<owning class>]` object for the first parameter is if you decorate it with `builtins.classmethod`; no other custom implementation of any typing construct will work, not even a direct subclass of `classmethod` with no implementation in the body.

As you've found, this is the reason for your runtime error.

If you are specifically using `mypy`, In the example you gave, I would tweak it like this:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import collections.abc as cx
import typing as t

clsT = t.TypeVar("clsT", bound=type)
P = t.ParamSpec("P")
R_co = t.TypeVar("R_co", covariant=True)

all_methods: list[classmethod[t.Any]] = []

def register_classmethod(classmeth: cx.Callable[[clsT], R_co]) -> classmethod[R_co]:
    # The assertion performs type-narrowing; see 
    # https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/type_narrowing.html
    assert isinstance(classmeth, classmethod)
    all_methods.append(classmeth)  # type: ignore[unreachable]
    return classmeth

class Class(object):
    @register_classmethod
    @classmethod
    def my_class_method(cls) -> None:
        print(f"Hello from {cls}.my_class_method")

    # Not a callable!
    my_class_method()  # mypy: "classmethod[None]" not callable [operator]

    @classmethod
    def run_registered_classmethods(cls) -> None:
        for classmeth in all_methods:
            classmeth.__func__(cls)

    # Too many arguments
    @register_classmethod  # mypy: Argument 1 to "register_classmethod" has incompatible type "Callable[[Type[Class], int], None]"; expected "Callable[[type], None]" [arg-type]
    @classmethod
    def bad_too_many_args(cls, a: int) -> None:
        return


Class.run_registered_classmethods()
```

If you're doing anything more with `classmethod`s and require proper type-checking in all scopes, I would re-implement the typing for `classmethod`, as follows:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import collections.abc as cx
import typing as t


# This is strictly unnecessary, but demonstrates a more accurately implemented
# `classmethod`. Accessing this from inside the class body, from an instance, or from
# a class works as expected.
# Unfortunately, you cannot use `ClassMethod` as a decorator and expect
# the first parameter to be typed correctly (see explanation 2.)
if t.TYPE_CHECKING:
    import sys

    clsT = t.TypeVar("clsT", bound=type)
    P = t.ParamSpec("P")
    R_co = t.TypeVar("R_co", covariant=True)

    class ClassMethod(t.Generic[clsT, P, R_co]):
        # Largely re-implemented from typeshed stubs; see
        # https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/d2d706f9d8b1a568ff9ba1acf81ef8f6a6b99b12/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L128-L139
        @property
        def __func__(self) -> cx.Callable[t.Concatenate[clsT, P], R_co]: ...
        @property
        def __isabstractmethod__(self) -> bool: ...
        def __new__(cls, __f: cx.Callable[t.Concatenate[clsT, P], R_co]) -> ClassMethod[clsT, P, R_co]:...
        def __get__(self, __obj: t.Any, __type: type) -> cx.Callable[P, R_co]: ...
        if sys.version_info >= (3, 10):
            __name__: str
            __qualname__: str
            @property
            def __wrapped__(self) -> cx.Callable[t.Concatenate[clsT, P], R_co]: ...  # Same as `__func__`
else:
    ClassMethod = classmethod


all_methods: list[ClassMethod[type, [], t.Any]] = []


def register_classmethod(
    classmeth: cx.Callable[[clsT], R_co]
) -> ClassMethod[clsT, [], R_co]:
    # The assertion performs type-narrowing; see 
    # https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/type_narrowing.html
    assert isinstance(classmeth, ClassMethod)
    all_methods.append(classmeth)  # type: ignore[unreachable]
    return classmeth


class Class(object):
    @register_classmethod
    @classmethod
    def my_class_method(cls) -> None:
        print(f"Hello from {cls}.my_class_method")

    # Not a callable! Fixes problem given in explanation 1.
    my_class_method()  # mypy: "ClassMethod[Type[Class], [], None]" not callable [operator]

    @classmethod
    def run_registered_classmethods(cls) -> None:
        for classmeth in all_methods:
            classmeth.__func__(cls)
            # Not enough arguments
            classmeth.__func__()  # mypy: Too few arguments [call-arg]

    # Too many arguments - `typing.ParamSpec` is working correctly
    @register_classmethod  # mypy: Argument 1 to "register_classmethod" has incompatible type "Callable[[Type[Class], int], None]"; expected "Callable[[type], None]" [arg-type]
    @classmethod
    def bad_too_many_args(cls, a: int) -> None:
        return


Class.run_registered_classmethods()


# `__get__` working correctly - on the descriptor protocol.
# These two error out both for static type checking and runtime.
Class.my_class_method(type)  # mypy: Too few arguments [call-arg]
Class.my_class_method.__func__  # mypy: "Callable[[], None]" has no attribute "__func__" [attr-defined]
```

Comment: Indeed, using an `assert` (or, even better, a `cast(classmethod)`) as in your first example does work out nicely.  I'm curious out your `ignore[unreachable]` tag, which my quick tests did not require.

Comment: @YannDirson `assert` is generally better for programmatic safety, especially in API code like `register_classmethod` (which only runs once per `classmethod` upon module import, so there is no concern about performance). As it stands, based on the type annotation, `register_classmethod` technically accepts a free function or a `@staticmethod` whose first parameter is annotated as `type`, and you don't actually want that to silently accumulate in `all_methods`.

Comment: @YannDirson `ignore[unreachable]` is because I tend to run `mypy` with full strictness checks - see https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/error_code_list2.html#check-that-statement-or-expression-is-unreachable-unreachable and https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-strict

Comment: Oh whoops - I didn't realise that `--strict` doesn't turn --warn-unreachable on. I've got it turned on in my `mypy` settings. Generally speaking, `--warn-unreachable` is nice for unnecssary comparisons and bad programmatic flow, but due it turns up a false positive here due to the special-casing of `classmethod`.